# Skipping tests in some modules in Maven

Tags: maven, unit-testing, junit, maven-2, build-process

I would like my Maven builds to run most unit tests. But there are unit tests in one project which are slower and I'd like to generally exclude them; and occasionally turn them on.

**Question**: How do I do this?

I know about `-Dmaven.test.skip=true`, but that turns off all unit tests.

I also know about skipping integration tests, described [here](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Maven+and+Integration+Testing). But I do not have integration tests, just unit tests, and I don't have any explicit calls to the  maven-surefire-plugin. (I am using Maven 2 with the Eclipse-Maven plugin).

Answer (score 94, accepted):

What about skipping tests only in this module ?

In the pom.xml of this module:

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <skipTests>true</skipTests>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

Eventually, you can create a profile that will disable the tests (still the pom.xml of the module) :

```
<project>
  [...]
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>noTest</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>noTest</name>
          <value>true</value>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
            <configuration>
              <skipTests>true</skipTests>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  [...]
</project>
```

With the latter solution, if you run `mvn clean package`, it will run all tests. If you run `mvn clean package -DnoTest=true`, it will not run the tests for this module.

Comment: Thanks that worked. The first code snippet skips the test; I may later use your further suggestion to define another profile.

My confusion was in the fact that my pom was   invoking surefire implicitly. There was no mention of the surefire plugin in my pom.xml.  Nonetheless, the code to configure the surefire plugin correctly did so.

Comment: For others, another option is to skip the whole module until you want to build and verify it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5542779/543935

Comment: And here is how to create maven profile that will run tests only in case it's activated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34334257/why-maven-runs-profile-plugin-even-if-profile-is-not-activated/41808680#41808680

Comment: How do you do this for all but a few modules in the project?

Comment: Can someone explain to me what is the use of `noTest` here?

Answer (score 39):

I think this is easier, and also has the benefit of working for non-surefire tests (in my case, FlexUnitTests)

```
<profile>
   <id>noTest</id>
    <properties>
       <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
    </properties>
 </profile>
```

Comment: This won't skip testing here, with or without -DnoTest=true

Comment: Thats cause you should use -PnoTest instead of -DnoTest=true

Comment: Setting maven.test.skip to true also has the effect of skipping test compilation, where as skipTests still compiles the tests but doesn't run them.

Answer (score 15):

If you have a large multi-module project and you would like to skip tests only in certain modules without the need to change each of the module `pom.xml` file with custom configuration and profiling, you could add the following to the parent `pom.xml` file:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.12</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>regex-property</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>regex-property</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <name>maven.test.skip</name>
                        <value>${project.artifactId}</value>
                        <regex>(module1)|(module3)</regex>
                        <replacement>true</replacement>
                        <failIfNoMatch>false</failIfNoMatch>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<modules>
    <module>module1</module>
    <module>module2</module>
    <module>module3</module>
</modules>
```

Thanks to the `build-helper-maven-plugin` you would actually dynamically check whether you are in a certain module or not during the build, via the `project.artifactId` property (pointing at each `artifactId` module during the build), the regex would then seek matching for certain values (the module names for which you want to skip tests) and populated the `maven.test.skip` property accordingly (setting it to `true`).

In this case, tests will be skipped for `module1` and `module3` while running properly for `module2`, that is, as expressed by the regex.

The advantage of this approach is to have it dynamic and centralized (in the parent `pom.xml`) hence better for maintenance: you could add or remove modules at any time simply by changing the simple regex above.

Obviously, if this is not the default behavior of the build (recommended case), you could always wrap the snippet above in a [maven profile](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html).

---

You could also go further and have dynamic behavior based on your input:

```
<properties>
    <test.regex>none</test.regex>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.12</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>regex-property</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>regex-property</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <name>maven.test.skip</name>
                        <value>${project.artifactId}</value>
                        <regex>${test.regex}</regex>
                        <replacement>true</replacement>
                        <failIfNoMatch>false</failIfNoMatch>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Here we are actually replacing the regex value with a property, `test.regex`, with default value to `none` (or whatever would not match any module name or, also, the default skipping matchings required).

Then from command line we could have

```
mvn clean test -Dtest.regex="(module1)" > will skip tests only for module1
mvn clean test -Dtest.regex="(module1)|(module2)" > will skip tests on module1 and module2
mvn clean test -Dtest.regex="(module1)|(module2)|(module3)" > will skip the three module tests
mvn clean test -Dtest.regex=".+" > will skip all module tests
mvn clean test > would not skip anything (or fall back on default behavior)
```

That is, then at runtime you decide, without any need to change the `pom.xml` file or activating any profile.

Comment: The only way I managed to execute this was by calling the `validate` phase explicitly. This didn't work for me when using another phase, like `package` or `install`. Looked promising though.

Comment: I can't this to work in _any_ case, unfortunately.  When the regex doesn't match, it sets `maven.test.skip` to `none` instead of leaving it alone, and whether it matches or doesn't match `maven-surefire-plugin` completely ignores it.

Answer (score 4):

Using Surefire Plugin 2.19 you can simply exclude the tests you don't want using regular expressions:

`mvn '-Dtest=!%regex[.*excludedString.*]' test`

The above command will exclude all the tests that contain *excludedString*.

**NB1** If double quotation mark(") is used instead of apostrophe(') the command will not be interpreted properly and will produce unexpected results. (Tested using bash 3.2.57)

**NB2** Particular attention should be paid to projects in which multiple version of the surefire plugin is used. Versions of surefire older than 2.19 will not execute any tests because they do not support regular expressions.

Version management(it might be a good idea to add this in the parent pom file):

```
<build>
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.1</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Examples of build commands that skip tests: https://artbcode.wordpress.com/2016/11/28/how-to-skip-a-subset-of-the-unit-tests/

Comment: Any idea how to skip multiple patterns?

Comment: `-Dtests` doesn't play nicely with surefire it seems. The following causes ALL my tests to get skipped: `mvn '-Dtest=!%regex[.*DeviceLogServiceTest.*]'  --quiet install  -Dsurefire.useFile=false -Dsurefire.printSummary=false -Dmaven.test.skip=false`

Comment: I'm using `mvn install "-Dtest=!%regex[.*excludedString.*]" -Dsurefire.failIfNoSpecifiedTests=false` to avoid testing modules with Java packages name containing `excludedString`.

Answer (score 2):

I had a slightly different need from this question that may prove helpful. I wanted to exclude from the command line a few different tests from different packages, so a single wildcard would not do it.

I found in the Maven Failsafe documentation rules for exclusions that you can specify a comma-separated list of either regex or wildcard exclusions:
https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html

So my pomfile looked like this:

```
<excludes>
    <exclude>${exclude.slow.tests}</exclude>
</excludes>
```

and my command line included this:

```
mvn install "-Dexclude.slow.tests=**/SlowTest1.java, **/package/ofslowtests/*.java, **/OtherSlowTest.java"
```

For me the key ingredient was getting a bunch of tests into one maven property in a single exclude statement.

Answer (score 0):

For maven-surefire-plugin I would suggest a bit different approach with environment variables or properties.

In my case I need to use parameter `testSourceDirectory`. But this parameter is not supported by profiles, so I cannot use them. And using profiles means too many new lines of code. It makes pom.xml more complicated.

**Environment variable:**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <skipTests>${env.SKIP_UNIT_TESTS}</skipTests>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Set it to `true` if you need to skip tests for the module. If it's not set, parameter `skipTests` will be ignored, so tests will run.

**Properties:**

```
<properties>
    <skipUnitTests>false</skipUnitTests>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>${skipUnitTests}</skipTests>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

To skip tests, run mvn with `-DskipUnitTests=true`