# How to exclude unit tests from the report of functional tests?

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, jenkins, jacoco-maven-plugin

My project structure is as follows:

```
myapp
+- module1
|  +- src/main
|  \- src/unit-tests
+- module2
|  +- src/main
|  \- src/unit-tests
+- module-FT
|  +- src/tests
|  \- pom.xml
\- pom.xml
```

In *Jenkins* job, the root pom is `pom.xml` (because I want the whole project to be built for *JaCoCo* reports on functional coverage), 
and when running the *Maven* goal for coverage report generation I have specify the pom as ***module-FT/pom.xml***.

Now when the test results are shown, it shows me a total being = FTs + all unit tests in other modules while I want to exclude the UTs from report generation.

But I dont think it has anything to do with *JaCoCo*, since I am talking about not the *JaCoCo* report but the Test Results. **The unit tests are also getting counted which I dont want.** I think this is so because in the *Maven* root pom below, I have given *pom.xml* which is causing the whole project to be built. But that's necessary for the *JaCoCo* to put out the coverage. I am not using *JaCoCo* plugin since the jenkins version is old and its beyond my scope to upgrade that.

[image]

Below are the *Jenkins* job details:

Build:

1. maven version: `maven 3.3.3`
2. root pom: `pom.xml`
3. Goals and options: `-B -U -X clean test -f functional-tests/pom.xml
   -DsuiteXmlFile=src/test/resources/suites/${TEST_SUITE} -Dhostname=${TEST_HOST} -Dprotocol=https -Dport=${TEST_PORT}`

Post Steps:

1. Execute shell

   ```
     #!/bin/bash
     # Cleanup workspace
     rm -rf target
     echo --------------------------------------
     echo TEST_HOST is ${TEST_HOST}
     echo manifestVersion is ${manifestVersion}
     echo --------------------------------------
     temp=${manifestVersion}
     appname=(${temp//-/ })
     manifestid=(${temp// / })
     echo appname is ${appname[0]}
     echo manifestid is ${manifestid[0]}


     mkdir -p ${WORKSPACE}/target/classes

     ### Copy class files to common folder for analysis
     cp -R ${WORKSPACE}/module-common/target/classes/* ${WORKSPACE}/target/classes
   cp -R ${WORKSPACE}/module-data/target/classes/* ${WORKSPACE}/target/classes
   cp -R ${WORKSPACE}/module-event/target/classes/* ${WORKSPACE}/target/classes
   cp -R ${WORKSPACE}/module-dependencies/target/classes/* ${WORKSPACE}/target/classes
   cp -R ${WORKSPACE}/module-core/target/classes/* ${WORKSPACE}/target/classes
   cp -R ${WORKSPACE}/module-api/target/classes/* ${WORKSPACE}/target/classes
   cp -R ${WORKSPACE}/module-legacy-api/target/classes/* ${WORKSPACE}/target/classes
   cp -R ${WORKSPACE}/module-messaging/target/classes/* ${WORKSPACE}/target/classes
   cp -R ${WORKSPACE}/module-service/target/classes/* ${WORKSPACE}/target/classes

   # build jacoco pom file in order to dump coverage file from app server
   echo '''
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
     <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
     <groupId>com.myorg</groupId>
     <artifactId>CodeCoverage</artifactId>
     <version>0.0.1</version>
     <build>
       <plugins>
         <!-- Dependencies -->
         <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
           <executions>
             <!-- Copy the ant tasks jar. Needed for ts.jacoco.report-ant . -->
             <execution>
               <id>jacoco-dependency-ant</id>
               <goals>
                 <goal>copy</goal>
               </goals>
               <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
               <inherited>false</inherited>
               <configuration>
                 <artifactItems>
                   <artifactItem>
                     <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                     <artifactId>org.jacoco.ant</artifactId>
                     <version>0.7.4.201502262128</version>
                   </artifactItem>
                 </artifactItems>
                 <stripVersion>true</stripVersion>
                 <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/jacoco-jars</outputDirectory>
               </configuration>
             </execution>
           </executions>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
           <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
           <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>0.7.4.201502262128</version>
           <executions>
             <execution>
               <id>default-cli</id>
               <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
               <goals>
                 <goal>dump</goal>
               </goals>
               <configuration>
                 <reset>${Reset}</reset>
                 <address>${TEST_HOST}</address>
               </configuration>
             </execution>
           </executions>
         </plugin>
         <!-- Ant plugin. -->
         <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>1.7</version>
           <executions>
             <execution>
               <id>report</id>
               <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
               <goals>
                 <goal>run</goal>
               </goals>
               <configuration>
                 <properties>
                     <srcdir>${env.srcDir}</srcdir>
                     <classdir>${env.clsDir}</classdir>
                     <appname>${env.appName}</appname>
                 </properties>
                 <target>
                   <property environment="env" />
                   <!-- Execute an ant task within maven -->
                   <echo message="Generating JaCoCo Reports" />
                   <taskdef name="report" classname="org.jacoco.ant.ReportTask">
                     <classpath path="${basedir}/target/jacoco-jars/org.jacoco.ant.jar" />
                   </taskdef>
                   <mkdir dir="${basedir}/target/coverage-report" />
                   <report>
                     <executiondata>
                       <fileset dir="${basedir}/target">
                         <include name="jacoco.exec" />
                       </fileset>
                     </executiondata>
                     <structure name="Raptor Coverage Project">
                       <group name="${env.appName}">
                         <classfiles>
                           <fileset dir="${env.clsDir}" />
                         </classfiles>
                         <sourcefiles encoding="UTF-8">
                           <fileset dir="${env.srcDir}" />
                         </sourcefiles>
                       </group>
                     </structure>
                     <html destdir="${basedir}/target/coverage-report/html" />
                     <xml destfile="${basedir}/target/coverage-report/coverage-report.xml" />
                     <csv destfile="${basedir}/target/coverage-report/coverage-report.csv" />
                   </report>
                 </target>
               </configuration>
             </execution>
           </executions>
           <dependencies>
             <dependency>
               <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
               <artifactId>org.jacoco.ant</artifactId>
               <version>0.7.4.201502262128</version>
             </dependency>
           </dependencies>
         </plugin>
       </plugins>
     </build>
   </project>''' > jacoco_pom.xml
   ```
2. Invoke top level maven targets:

   *Maven* version: *3.3.3*

   Goals: `-f jacoco_pom.xml jacoco:dump  antrun:run@report`

Comment: Could you please add the plugin configuration?

Comment: did you see [this page](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/examples/build/pom-it.xml) in the plugins public API?

Comment: Updated question. please check.

Answer (score 0):

Would suggest that you first structure your projects along the standard maven configuration. This isn't a requirement, but will save you some manual configuration.

```
modulexx
    src
        main/java
        test/java <-- Unit tests always expected here. Usually with suffix '***Test.java'
        it/java   <-- Integration tests always expected here. Usually with suffix '***IT.java'
```

You can then configure the Maven Surefire plugin and maven failsafe plugin for running your Unit tests and Integration tests separately, and produce independent reports. You'll find details in the links below for how to configure your pom.xml to use these separate folders.

http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/

http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/

Comment: FTs are located in external folder and it can not be changed. Check the edits I made please, it might make more sense.

Comment: You can still leverage the separate runners for maven to execute the tests. See the documentation for configuring source paths for integration tests. This will give you separate output folders for results which you can then configure your CI tooling to read

Comment: Hi, I followed the regex solution in http://stackoverflow.com/a/39562385/1841181.
But with this, in the jenkins job for test running and jacoco report making, I am getting error: `[ERROR] Could not find goal 'run@report' in plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3 among available goals help, run -> [Help 1]`

Comment: Sounds like a typo. Paste your full command line in a comment t

Comment: See the post steps in last part of post. The goal is there. Same. All in all see, the structure I have posted. Now I cant permanently modify pom of each module to exclude unit tests while the code build runs in jenkins, its needed. But I just want to exclude the modules that are not functional tests (only one is FT) from unit tests while code build is done. This because, when the build runs, then Jenkins shows a link called Test Results which shows how many tests have failed, passed.