# How to skip multiple test cases mvn

Tags: java, maven

Need flag to skip multiple test cases and not through pom.

`-Dtest=!abc.demo1IT and -Dtest=!*test`

Want to skip abc.demoIT and unit test cases using flag. How do I combine these 2?

`mvn -Dtest=[!abc.demo1IT |!*test] clean install` does not seem to work.

Referece from [Skipping tests in some modules in Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772735/skipping-tests-in-some-modules-in-maven)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41050211/1898563

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can exclude multiple patterns using a comma-separated list. Make sure you enclose it in quotes so that it's treated as a single option:

```
"-Dtest=!abc.demo1IT, !*test"
```

Reference: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#test

Comment: Thanks. 
-Dtest="!abc.demo1IT, !*test" worked